# How to check for EOF/EOL with Stream I/O in Fortran?

Tags: stream, io, fortran, eof, eol

I would like to use FORTRAN streaming I/O to make a program that tells me how many lines a text-file has. The idea is to make something like this:

```
OPEN(UNIT=10,ACCESS='STREAM',FILE='testfile.txt')

nLines=0
bContinue=.TRUE.

DO WHILE (bContinue)
   READ(UNIT=10) cCharacter
   IF (cCharacter.EQ.{EOL-char}) nLines=nLines+1
   IF (cCharacter.EQ.{EOF-char}) bContinue=.FALSE.
ENDDO
```

(I didn't include variable declaration but I think you get the idea of what they are; the only important clarification would be that that cCharacter has LEN=1)

My problem is that I don't know how to check if the character I just read from the file is an end-of-line or end-of-file (the "ifs" in the code). When you read and print characters this way, you eventually get newlines in the same place you had them in the original text, so I think it does read and recognize them as "characters", somehow. Perhaps turning the characters into integers and comparing to the appropriate number? Or is there a more direct way?

(I know that you can use the register reading (EDIT: I meant record reading) to do a program that reads lines more easily and add an IOstatus to check for eof, but the "line counter" is just a useful example, the idea is to learn how to move in a more controlled way through a textfile)

Answer (score 2):

Checking for a specific character as line terminator makes you program OS dependent.   It would be better to use the facilities of the language so that your program is compiler and OS dependent.   Since lines are basically records, why do this with steam I/O?   That request seems to make an easy job into a hard one.   If are can use regular IO, here is an example program to count the lines in a text file.

EDIT: the code fragment was changed into a program to answer questions in the comments.  With "line" as a character variable, when I test the program with gfortran and ifort I don't see a problem when the input file has empty or blank lines.

```
program test_lc

use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

integer :: LineCount, Read_Code
character (len=200) :: line


open (unit=51, file="temp.txt", status="old", access='sequential', form='formatted', action='read' )

LineCount = 0

ReadLoop: do

   read (51, '(A)', iostat=Read_Code)  line

   if ( Read_Code /= 0 ) then
      if ( Read_Code == iostat_end ) then
         exit ReadLoop    ! end of file --> line count found
      else
         write ( *, '( / "read error: ", I0 )' )  Read_Code
         stop
      end if
   end if

   LineCount = LineCount + 1

   write (*, '( I0, ": ''", A, "''" )' )  LineCount, trim (line)
   if ( len_trim (line) == 0 ) write (*, '("The above is an empty or all blank line.")' )

end do ReadLoop

write (*, *) "found", LineCount, " lines"

end program test_lc
```

If you want to do further processing of the file, you can rewind it.

P.S.

The main reason that I have used Fortran Stream IO is to read files produced by other languages, e.g., C

Portable methods are provided to write new-line boundaries; I'm not aware of a portable method to test for such.

Comment: Yes, I know the task I used as example can be done like that with record reading. However, there is a minor thing I would like to point out about your code: I don't know if this is only because of the compiler, the computer, or happens in all codes, but if you save your read in variable "line", it will just skip the empty lines. Since you are not using "line" for anything else, this can be fixed if you just "read" without saving it in any variable (this way all lines will be counted). However, for example, there is no way of knowing where are the empty lines in a text using register.

Comment: I know this may sound silly, but I would like to know a way of dealing with text files that is more versatile/precise than record reading (I used "register" in the main question but I meant record). For example, searching for a word would be much easier with stream than with record (copying exactly one part of the text is impossible because, as I said, if you read into a variable, it will skip eol). Do you know of a non-portable way of checking for EOL? How much "non-portable" is it? Obviously I would prefer a portable one, but knowing one imperfect way is better than knowing none.

Comment: How don't understand why you think reading test into lines/records isn't versatile.   Are you concerned about words getting broken across line boundaries?  Otherwise I don't see why searching for a word would be much easier using stream io.

Comment: If you see the file as a group of characters, it is easy to imagine how to check for a word or part of a word (check for the first letter, then check if the following is the appropriate, etc); moreover, you know how to locate it; you can simply return the position of the first letter as a character. With records, I don't see it that clearly how to look for a word or a part of a word (imagine for example that you are looking for "energy" and the text only has "totalenergy" altogether), and if you do, I don't see how to easily locate it (it is more tricky to define a "position" for a reg).

Comment: You check for words in a record (or line) just as you describe in your first sentence.  In fact, Fortran provides intrinsic procedures for this!  Possible differences are: 1) if you want to check for words that might be split across lines, and 2) if you want to count the starting character of the word from the start of the file and not from the start of the line.   For 2, just sum the lengths of the preceding lines.   A difficulty is trailing blanks are not significant.

Comment: Perhaps there is something about record reading that I don't fully understand, but I can't imagine how to do it. I mean, if you look for "energy", you say I should READ() sVariable (which is a character(Len=6))?? but that would only read the first word of each line. I know there is a way of reading continuously without changing line, but to do this you need to specify in "READ" the format (Advance='no'). Even so, it would read "totalenergy" as "totale" and would never recognize the word "energy". Am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: The standard approach is to guess the longest possible line length and declare the variable at that length.  Then when you read the record into the string, if the record is shorter the variable will be padded on the right with blanks.   This is not a problem is you are searching for non-blank words such as "energy" -- scan the string for the word as a sub-string.   It could be a problem is you want to distinguish between lines in the input file that are empty (i.e., have nothing in front of the line terminator) and those that have some number of blanks/spaces before the line terminator.

Comment: I didn't know that if you clarified the format you could read the whole line (because when you don't, it usually reads only one word, right?). And from you say I gather that this way doesn't skip empty lines either (right now differentiating empty lines from all space lines is not an issue). I will try and see if I can handle the lines once stored this way. I would still like to know if there is a way to check if the character is an eol, but just out of curiosity; you're probably right that the most practical way to navigate the text is this.